# Import data to database and retrieve

Tags: python, database

I have a raspberrypi giving data for every 5 minutes running in python. I need to store the data to a data base using wamp server and plot it in a graph (time vs data). I have no idea how to connect to wamp server to store and retrieve data.

Comment: look at this `https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
        connection.close()
```